# Does the difficulty of discrete logarithm depend on the difficulty of integer factorization?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, cryptography, factoring

The security of many (most? all?) public-key cryptography systems are based on the difficulty of the discrete logarithm or integer factorization. Are these two problems related at all?

With the discrete logarithm problem I mean the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $g$ and $h$ be elements of $G$ such that $h \in \langle g \rangle$. Find an integer $x$ such that $g^x = h$.

In particular I am interested in the case where $G = \mathbb{Z}_p^*$. If we know an efficient way to factor integers, does this help us in solving the discrete logarithm problem for a given $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$?

Conversely, if we know how to solve  the discrete logarithm problem efficiently for any group $G$ (or just $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$), does this help with factoring integers?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/75089

Comment: I am not so sure about your definition of "help". For instance, if you can factor integers in polynomial time then certainly you can solve discrete logarithm in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ in a faster time. This is because modern algorithms devote a significant amount of computation on factoring medium sized integers during a phase called "sieving". So if you are just asking about speedup in general then answer is affirmative ($\mathbb{Z}_p^*$). Your last question is answered in the MO article ($\mathbb{Z}_p^*$). DL on general Elliptic Curves is still open to my best of knowledge.

Comment: It has been suggested that this be migrated to [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/). Although this question is important to cryptology, it definitely seems to be a math problem, too. I suggest we leave it here for now. If it doesn't get a good answer in a while, we can think about migrating.

Answer (score 2):

> Are these two problems related at all?

The answer is yes, and it is at many levels. The [general number field sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_field_sieve), which is generally thought of as a factoring algorithm, is also very useful for [solving discrete logs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm_records).

**Theoretically**:
Solving the discrete log with a composite modulus is exactly as hard as factoring [[3](http://wstein.org/projects/john_gregg_thesis.pdf#page=43)]. However, it is not known if solving discrete log with a prime modulus leads to efficient factoring [[4](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/815/706)].

> If we know an efficient way to factor integers, does this help us in solving the discrete logarithm problem for a given $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$?
>
> Conversely, if we know how to solve the discrete logarithm problem efficiently for any group G  (or just $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$), does this help with factoring integers?

For composite modulus, the answer is yes. For prime modulus, we don't know.

A good reference for a lot of this information is [John Gregg's thesis page 43](http://wstein.org/projects/john_gregg_thesis.pdf#page=43).