# Discrete Logarithm vs Integer Factorization

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, cryptography, prime-factorization

Can anyone please tell me if finding discrete logarithm is considered more difficult than integer factorization?
We have very advanced methods to find factors of large composite numbers like Number Field Sieve. Do any such advanced method exist for finding discrete logarithm modulo prime?
This argument is also linked directly with saying which one among RSA or Elgamal cryptosystems is more strong.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317898/does-the-difficulty-of-discrete-logarithm-depend-on-the-difficulty-of-integer-fa

Comment: I want to know which of the 2 problems is considered harder to break?

Comment: Look at the answer for that question. "Theoretically: Solving the discrete log with a composite modulus is exactly as hard as factoring [3]. However, it is not known if solving discrete log with a prime modulus leads to efficient factoring [4]."